# When Overriding GetHashCode(), Entity Framework 6 Throws Exception on SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Executing the following two lines

```
DBContext.DbSet.Remove(DBContext.DbSet.First(x => x.Id == someExistingId));
DBContext.SaveChanges();
```

results in the following exception being thrown on `SaveChanges()` when I override `GetHashCode()` on the `DbSet` entity type.

> Adding a relationship with an entity which is in the Deleted state is not allowed.

I'm using a T4 Template to generate POCO objects and overriding `GetHashCode()` in a `partial`. If I comment out only the `GetHashCode()` override, the code executes as expected.

The `GetHashCode()` override just returns `Id.GetHashCode()`. `Id` is an `int`.

Is there some restriction related to overriding `GetHashCode()` with Entity Framework POCOs?

Comment: Do you think you could show us your code for overriding `GetHashCode` and the related properties/methods that are used in computing the hash? I think I know what's going on but it's only a guess until I see the code.

Comment: @Enigmativity The `GetHashCode()` override just returns `Id.GetHashCode()`. Was thinking about making it more complete but TBH I've not had to do more than that in the past.

Comment: And what is `Id`?

Comment: @Enigmativity `Id` is an `int`

Comment: Unless `Id` is mutable then it's not what I was thinking.

Comment: `Id` is technically mutable as it has a getter and setter but I would not expect the value to change between the the calls to `Remove()` and `SaveChanges()`. Open to any guesses :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the entity framework [documentation](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Support%20of%20POCO%20entities%20with%20custom%20Equals%20and%20GetHashCode%20implementations):

> - You should still follow the guidelines (Eric Lippert has a [great post on this](https://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/)) for implementing Equals and GetHashCode
> - If your
>   hashcode/equality algorithm cannot guarantee immutability and
>   uniqueness at all times then you need to make sure that your
>   collection navigation properties use reference equality for
>   comparisons. For HashSet pass
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.ObjectReferenceEqualityComparer to
>   the constructor (or create your own reference-based equality comparer,
>   something like the snippet below should work). Do not use List as
>   it will always use the overridden Equals method for methods like
>   Remove.

```
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        Products = new HashSet<Product>(new ObjectReferenceEqualityComparer());
    }

    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
public sealed class ObjectReferenceEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<object>
{
    bool IEqualityComparer<object>.Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        return ReferenceEquals(x, y);
    }

    int IEqualityComparer<object>.GetHashCode(object obj)
    {
        return RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had assumed that I had been following the `Rule: the integer returned by GetHashCode must never change while the object is contained in a data structure that depends on the hash code remaining stable`.
But maybe when EF first creates the instances from the DB it uses the default ctor and no properties including the Id are set initially? 
In hindsight this solution seems obvious.